# expect language, how to keep the spawned program running while the expect script is closed

Tags: ssh, tcl, expect

```
spawn ssh -fnqX username@192.168.1.100 google-chrome 
expect -re "password"  
send "passwd\r"
interact (?)
```

how to keep running the chrome while the whole script is close. so I can do another thing in the same shell?
thank you very much.

new added.

```
spawn ssh -fnqX $log_name@192.168.1.100 firefox  
expect -re "password"  
send "$passwd_v100\r"
expect -re "failed to create drawable| ~"
send eof\r
```

actually, I wrote the above code later, and it runs correctly. well, I do donot know how the  code `send eof\r` makes the script run well. I think it strange. BTW, the string "failed to create drawable" is invoked by the firefox.

Comment: you could just invoke the expect program in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Using [nohup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) maybe?

Comment: I mean using the expect to perform this action. I tried the nohup and & ,but the result is random (chrome randomly runs, in other words, sometimes chrome runs, while another time it does not run).

Comment: @vz33, this *might* relate to the fact that to properly run an application which talks to an X server (Chrome in your case), that application has to know how to connect to that X server. Usually it either has a command-line option(s) for this or it looks to the `DISPLAY` env. variable, or both. So I'd start investigating there.

Comment: spawn ssh -fnqX $log_name@192.168.1.100 firefox  \n
    expect -re "password"  \n
    send "$passwd_v100\r"
    expect -re "failed to create drawable| ~"
    send eof\r
actually, I wrote the above code later, and it runs correctly. well, I do donot know how the  code `send eof\r` makes the script run well. I think it strange.

Comment: @kostic,     just see the question. I cannot write the code in the comment area.

Comment: @vz33, I've no idea: `send eof\r` supposedly sends a EOF signal to the remote shell supposedly producing the same result you normally do when hitting `Ctrl-d` in an interactive SSH session, and there it's equivalent to executing `exit` in the shell, that is, to quitting the shell. This is all I can say on this matter.